# Is there a way to uniquely identity a dynamically added element?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to `dynamically` `load` a bunch of `posts` from a API and then implement a `like button` for each of them.

```
function load_allposts(){
    fetch("/posts")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(posts => {
        var enc = document.createElement('div');
        enc.className = "post-enc";
        let s = ``;
        posts.forEach(element => {
            s += `<div class="p-container">
                    <div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" class="profile-btn" data-id=${element[0].author_id}> ${element[0].author_name} </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-body">
                        ${element[0].body}
                    </div>
                    <div class="p1">
                        <span class="like-status">${element[0].likes}</span>  people like this
                        <button class="like-btn">${element[1]}</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-time">
                        ${element[0].timestamp}
                    </div>
                </div>`;
        });
        enc.innerHTML = s;
        document.querySelector('#all-posts').appendChild(enc);
    });
}
```

I would to like to modify the `<span class="like-status">` element when I click the `<button class="like-btn">`. The only way that I can think of to get a reference to `<span class="like-status">` is by adding a `ID` to it by implementing some kind of `counter`, which I feel is more like a hack rather than real solution.

I tried googling but almost all solutions involved `JQuery`, which I am not familiar with. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't your `posts` have some kind of id that you could use to set it to the label? Otherwise, you could use the `index`-Argument in the `forEach()` function like `posts.forEach((element, index) => {...}` to avoid a counter but still have a (somewhat) unique ID as long as you do not fetch any more posts.

Comment: @David Losert That is a actually a good idea. But lets say I have multiple labels in the same post, in which case we would end up with same id for multiple labels.

Comment: What you are saying is a hack, is actually a perfectly fine solution to your problem. Add an id with the counter and you have a unique identifier for each element.

Comment: @DavidLosert is right, you should do something like `<span class="like-status" id="${element[0].id}_likes">${element[0].likes}</span>` and then in the button `onClick` use `"${element[0].id}_likes"` to get the span item

Comment: @LoneWolf : You could do it like @Onheiron says by simply extending that Id with a specific, static string for that label (they used `${id}_likes`), so +1 for @Onheirons solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`delegate event binding`](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) `document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {` to trigger click event for dynamically added button.

It will raise `click` on every element inside `document` you need to find if it is one which you expect with `event.target.matches('button.like-btn')`.

Then you can find your `span` with getting `parent` and then finding `span.like-status` using `querySelector`.

Try it below. For demo modified `load_allposts`. You do not need to do any change in it.

```js
load_allposts();

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.matches('button.like-btn')) {
    let span = event.target.parentElement.querySelector('span.like-status');
    span.innerText = 'Modified';
  }
});

function load_allposts() {

  let posts = [1]
  var enc = document.createElement('div');
  enc.className = "post-enc";
  let s = ``;
  posts.forEach(element => {
    s += `<div class="p-container">
                    <div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" class="profile-btn" data-id=element[0].author_id> element[0].author_name </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-body">
                        element[0].body
                    </div>
                    <div class="p1">
                        <span class="like-status">element[0].likes</span>  people like this
                        <button class="like-btn">element[1]</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-time">
                        element[0].timestamp
                    </div>
                </div>`;
  });
  enc.innerHTML = s;
  document.querySelector('#all-posts').appendChild(enc);
}
```

```html
<div id='all-posts'>
</div>
```

---

**Note** event delegation have extra overhead so alternatively you can use below code.

Here added two functions added as below and added one line `bindClickEvent(enc);` at end of `load_allposts` function.

- `likeClick` - perform custom logic to update span.like-status
- `bindClickEvent` - bind click event to all button.like-btn inside div
- Call `bindClickEvent(enc);` at end of `load_allposts` function.

Try it below.

```js
load_allposts();

// perform custom logic to update span.like-status
function likeClick(event) {
  // querySelector will return first matching element
  let span = event.target.parentElement.querySelector('span.like-status');
  span.innerText = 'Modified';
}

// bind click event to all button.like-btn inside div
function bindClickEvent(enc) {
  // querySelectorAll will return array of all matching elements
  let buttons = enc.querySelectorAll('button.like-btn');
  // loop over each button and assign click function
  for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].onclick = likeClick;
  }
}

function load_allposts() {

  let posts = [1]
  var enc = document.createElement('div');
  enc.className = "post-enc";
  let s = ``;
  posts.forEach(element => {
    s += `<div class="p-container">
                    <div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" class="profile-btn" data-id=element[0].author_id> element[0].author_name </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-body">
                        element[0].body
                    </div>
                    <div class="p1">
                        <span class="like-status">element[0].likes</span>  people like this
                        <button class="like-btn">element[1]</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-time">
                        element[0].timestamp
                    </div>
                </div>`;
  });
  enc.innerHTML = s;
  document.querySelector('#all-posts').appendChild(enc);

  // assign click event to buttons inside enc div.
  bindClickEvent(enc);
}
```

```html
<div id='all-posts'>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer. I really appreciate it. I don't really understand why event delegation would be more expensive than the alternate method but that's a different topic altogether. Thanks again.

Comment: In `event delegation` it will trigger `click` on any element from `document`, so when you click on span or text or div it will invoke it. And we handle it inside with condition `if (event.target.matches('button.like-btn'))` and performing required logic only when we get desired element.